# Ansible - List of dictionaries

Tags: ansible

Let me introduce my problem. I have some list of dictionary in my Ansible code:

```yaml
my_example_list = [
    {
        "key1" : "value_of_first_key"
    },
    {
        "key2": "value_of_second_key"
    },
    {
        "key3": "value_of_third_key"
    }
]
```

I need execute command which will iterate over this list and it should look something like:

```yaml
 - name: 'Example'
   shell: 'Here is my {{ item.key }} and here is {{ item.value }}'
```

What I've do or try to do:

I was trying to do that with `with_items` but i'm not able to point into value of particular key.

I've also try to filter values using `| first` and `| last` but it's not worked in my case.

What I want to achieve:

Creating loop which will iterate via that list and inject separated key and value into command.

I was asked to show how I was trying to resolve my issue:

Here is some code:

```yaml
# Showing last component failing
- name: "Try to show last component of my list"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ my_example_list[1] | last }}"

# When i'm trying to show first component of my list i get "key1"
- name: "Try to show first component of my list"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ my_example_list[1] | first }}"

# This shows me my list of dict
- name: "Trying use with_items"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_example_list }}"

# But when i'm trying point to key and value for example 
- name: "Trying use with_items point to key and value"
  debug:
    msg: "Here is my {{ item.key }} which keep {{ item.value }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_example_list }}"

# It's failing.
```

Sorry it's not maybe solution with using loop. I'm just stack with that issue over few days... And as first step I want to know how correctly point to pair keys and values.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It also works well:

```yaml
  - name: Correct solution
    debug:
      msg: "This is my {{ item.key }} and my value {{ item.value }}"
    with_dict: "{{ my_example_list }}"
```

Thanks @U880D for help! I'm not able to add some plus for your solution because I'm new joiner. Appreciate your answer! :)

Comment: Right, a loop [`with_dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict) is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure and naming seems to be unfavorable. There is no need to number the key name and therefore it should be avoided. Furthermore counting list elements in Python starts at `0` not `1`.

The following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    example_list: |
      [
        {
          "key1" : "value_of_first_key"
        },
        {
          "key2": "value_of_second_key"
        },
        {
          "key3": "value_of_third_key"
        }
      ]

  tasks:

  - name: Example loop
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} is of type {{ item | type_debug }}"
    loop: "{{ example_list }}"

  - name: Example loop
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.values() }}"
    loop: "{{ example_list }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example loop] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'key1': u'value_of_first_key'}) =>
  msg: '{u''key1'': u''value_of_first_key''} is of type dict'
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'key2': u'value_of_second_key'}) =>
  msg: '{u''key2'': u''value_of_second_key''} is of type dict'
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'key3': u'value_of_third_key'}) =>
  msg: '{u''key3'': u''value_of_third_key''} is of type dict'


TASK [Example loop] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'key1': u'value_of_first_key'}) =>
  msg:
  - value_of_first_key
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'key2': u'value_of_second_key'}) =>
  msg:
  - value_of_second_key
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'key3': u'value_of_third_key'}) =>
  msg:
  - value_of_third_key
```

**Further Readings**

- [How to work with lists and dictionaries in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-lists-dictionaries-yaml)
- [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)